# If $f(x)=1-f(x-a_1)f(x-a_2)...f(x-a_n)$, prove that $f$ is eventually periodic. (Czech and Slovak 2001)

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math, functional-equations, periodic-functions

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be positive integers.  Suppose that $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb R$ is given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x<0,\\
1-f(x-a_1)f(x-a_2)...f(x-a_n)&x\ge 0.\end{cases}$$
Show that there exist positive integers $s,t$ st  for all integers $x>s$, $f(x+t)=f(x)$.

Source : https://imomath.com/othercomp/Czs/CzsMO01.pdf

My attempt :

By induction, we can see that $f(x)=0$ or $1$ for all $x$.  Therefore, $f(x)^2=f(x)$.  Hence we can assume that $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$.

If $n=1$, then $f(x+2a_1)=1-f(x+a_1)=1-(1-f(x))=f(x)$ for every $x\ge -a_1$.  So we can take $s=1$ and $t=2a_1$ in this case.

If $n=2$, I think we can take $t=a_1+a_2$.  Not sure yet...

Edit to add : Is it possible to find an exact formula for the minimum period $t$ in terms of $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$?

Comment: Do you know how to show that the fibonacci sequence modulo any integer is eventually periodic? You can apply the same idea here.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how to apply that here.  Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Any consecutive sequence of $\max(a_i)$ values on positive integers will uniquely determine the subsequent sequence.

**Hint:** Show that there is some sequence of $\max(a_i)$ integers that repeats by Pigeonhole Principle on $2^{\max(a_i)} + \max(a_i)$ terms

Hence, the sequence is eventually periodic.

Comment: Do you think whether there is a nice formula for the minimum period (depending on $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$)?

Comment: @ipst I don't know. I don't think so, but I've not investigated.